# Faces read, made new

Tags: word, affix-riddle

My prefix is angry, and sure to make you, too,

My infix is de la Cité, en France,

My suffix is the law, to France’s bro.

My whole is my title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My prefix is angry, and sure to make you, too,

> To **RILE** is to make angry.

My infix is de la Cité, en France,

> The **ILE** de la Cité is an island in the Seine in Paris. Notre-Dame cathedral is located there.

My suffix is the law, to France's bro.

> **LEY** means law in Spanish. Spain is adjacent to France.

My whole is my title.

> You are a **RILEY**, or, as the tag taxonomists say, an [affix-riddle](/questions/tagged/affix-riddle).

Comment: Explain the title? (a cryptic clue, 8 letters)